# SpringBoot Data JPA groupby

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to execute a group by query using springboot jpa specfications. But I am facing error. Below is my code.

```
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee> {
  
   default List<Employee> findAllActiveEmployee(String activeInd) {
     return findAll(filterByActiveAndGroupByGenderName);
   }
   
   private Specification<Employee> filterByActiveAndGroupByGenderName(String activeInd) {
     return (root, query, builder) -> {
        query.multiselect(List.of(root.get("name"), root.get("gender")));
        query.groupBy(root.get("name"), root.get("gender")));
        return builder.equal(root.get("activeInd"), activeInd);
     }; 
   }
}
```

But with above code, group by is getting added but columns provided in select is not getting appended and instead entire columns of Employee class is getting added and throwing "Not a GroupBy expression" error.

I am trying like - select name, gender from Employee where active_ind='Y' group by name, gender

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA Specification is a good tool to write your queries in a type-safe way. However, it is not suitable for every situation. One of the limitations is that it doesn't support group by queries with the `@Query` annotation.

You can work around this by using a combination of a 'native query' and a 'projection'. Here is an example:

```java
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT new com.yourpackage.EmployeeDetails(e.name, e.gender) FROM Employee e WHERE e.activeInd = :activeInd GROUP BY e.name, e.gender")
    List<EmployeeDetails> findAllActiveEmployee(@Param("activeInd") String activeInd);

}
```

You need to create the `EmployeeDetails` projection that consists of fields `name` and `gender`.

```java
package com.yourpackage;

public class EmployeeDetails {
    private final String name;
    private final String gender;

    public EmployeeDetails(String name, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    // getters
}
```

Note that this approach only works for JPQL and SQL ('native queries'). This is because Hibernate (which is underneath Spring JPA) allows constructors to be used in the `SELECT` clause, which it then translates to a ResultSet that gets transformed into the objects you require.